# Android firebase app indexing search suggestions update perid

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

As far as i can see there is gap between app with integrated firebase app indexing installed, and moment when indexed content appear as suggestions when user type query in google search bar. 
I can't figure out how it works and what is the period of time user need to wait to see suggestions.
Does developer need to take some actions to force app-indexed-content appearance in search? I mean appearance not as result of search in "IN APPS" tab, but as a suggestion - check attached image: [image]

Comment: How long a gap? Do you mean the autocomplete isn't working for several days after App Indexing works, or a delay in rendering the autocomplete?

Comment: @LaurenceMoroney autocomplete doesn't work for 10-60 mins. On some devices. Actually i didn't found precise pattern when it happens (is it device dependent, or android, or google play services device "back-end" version).

Comment: + i mean auto complete of google search works well, but my items appear in auto-suggestion list with delay 10-60mins.

Comment: in my case, delay is too long. I've implemented this feature 3 hours ago and see content in "IN APPS" tab, but not in suggestions :(

Comment: @ZakharovRoman check on google devices. I assume that behavior may be different on custom vendor roms. Try to implement indexing service as in tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the indexable item to appear in the auto complete suggestions, you must also record a view action after adding the item to the index

```
FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().start(Actions.newView(item.getTitle(),"http://example.com/item?id=5"))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Why? Why has google put this restriction? Do you have more info?

Comment: Probably so users only see items they've previously viewed. A dictionary app would not want to show ''aardvark' every time you type in 'a' into search. But in some cases they would, especially when linking a users' web dictionary account history to a new app download. This behavior is fine, but should really be documented.

I would guess that this feature has gone unloved because the focus has moved onto app actions and the new search suggestions inherent in P. This wouldn't be the first time Google did this. The Search content provider was quietly silently deprecated before 5.0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then why developer would index the data if they don't want to see in the autocomplete list of Google Search?

Comment: It took me a while to figure about this behavier and finally I saw your answer on another question and it worked for me. Thanks again for the correct answer. Yes, they don;t have correct and clear document for it.